# Issue with installing PyLucene 6.5.0 on Linux

Tags: linux, python-3.x, lucene, pylucene, jcc

I recently moved to python3, so I'm trying to install the recent version of Pylucene (version 6.5.0) which is compatible with python3.

```
jcc3/sources/jcc.cpp: In function ‘PyObject* t_jccenv_strhash(PyObject*, PyObject*)’:
jcc3/sources/jcc.cpp:214:27: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘PRIxMAX’
     sprintf(buffer, "%0*" PRIxMAX, (int) hexdig, hash);
                           ^
jcc3/sources/jcc.cpp:214:54: warning: conversion lacks type at end of format [-Wformat=]
     sprintf(buffer, "%0*" PRIxMAX, (int) hexdig, hash);
                                                      ^
jcc3/sources/jcc.cpp:214:54: warning: too many arguments for format [-Wformat-extra-args]
error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
```

But, to install the jcc I get the following error which I have no idea why it occurs:
Do you have any idea about this issue?

Thank you in advance,
Amin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem, was solved by setting __STDC_FORMAT_MACROS:

My JCC_CFLAGS is set to:

```
export JCC_CFLAGS="-v;-fno-strict-aliasing;-Wno-write-strings;-D__STDC_FORMAT_MACROS"
```

An example of an automated build script of JCC for conda is available at:

https://github.com/conda-forge/jcc-feedstock/blob/master/recipe/build.sh